# Azure Automation script to read json file

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I've been using Azure Automation for a couple tasks such as shutting down VMs, removing cloud service slots (staging) when we aren't using it.

This all works great, I have a lot of these VM/cloud service name defined in the code itself. I want to make it a little cleaner for our team to work with. My idea was to define a json file with this information and have the script read the values from the json file.

Does Azure Automation allow the use of a json file? I don't see it as a "Setting type". If that capability isn't allowed does anyone have any other creative ways to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using the variable type (string) to store json. The UI's one-line dialog is not optimal for viewing the data, but storing it shouldn't be a problem. You can use PowerShell's convertfrom-json to read the data

```
workflow jsontest
{
$a = Get-automationVariable -name "jsontest"
$ba = $a | convertfrom-json
}
```

A better approach might be to save the json data as a text file and store it elsewhere, such as blob storage but that depends on how often the data changes I guess.

Comment: I agree with this advice. Just to add to it a bit, if you go the "store the file on Azure Blob Storage" route, you will need to download the file to the Azure Automation sandbox as part of the runbook. Calling this runbook inline can be used to do that: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/a-Blob-from-Azure-Storage-6bc13745. If you go the "store the JSON in an Automation variable asset" route, note that if you don't want to use the UI to set the JSON the variable should contain (since its single line view only), you can also call Set-AutomationVariable within a runbook to do so.

Comment: @joe thanks for the additional solution. I went with the blob storage approach, much cleaner imo